# Suppose bowl 1 has 2 red/4 blue, bowl 2 has 1 red/2 blue, bowl 3 has 5 red/4 blue

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose bowl 1 has 2 red/4 blue, bowl 2 has 1 red/2 blue, bowl 3 has 5 red/4 blue.

Also suppose that the probability of picking the bowls is:

$P(B1) = \frac{1}{3}; P(B2) = \frac{1}{6}; P(B3) = \frac{1}{2}$

What is the probability of drawing a red coin?

---

My approach:

I can treat this problem as conditional probability:

P(red ball|B1 was chosen) + P(red ball|B2 was chosen) + P(red ball|B3 was chosen)

This equals:

$$\frac{P(\text{B1 was chosen | red ball) $\times$ P(red ball)}}{P(\text{B1 was chosen})}$$ + $$\frac{P(\text{B2 was chosen | red ball) $\times$ P(red ball)}}{P(\text{B2 was chosen})}$$ +
$$\frac{P(\text{B3 was chosen | red ball) $\times$ P(red ball)}}{P(\text{B3 was chosen})}$$

This equals

$$\frac{P(\text{B1 was chosen | red ball) $\times$ $\frac{2}{6}$}}{\frac{1}{3}}$$ + $$\frac{P(\text{B2 was chosen | red ball) $\times$ $\frac{1}{3}$}}{\frac{1}{6}}$$ + $$\frac{P(\text{B3 was chosen | red ball) $\times$ $\frac{5}{9}$}}{\frac{1}{2}}$$

---

What I don't know how to do is the probability of P($B_i \text{ chosen | red ball})$.

I think ... since all three bowls have red balls, then it's a pretty likely chance, so $\frac{1}{3}$, but when I plug in that fraction, my probability comes out over 100$\%$, and that's wrong.

Comment: Why not simply find out $\Sigma P(red ball \cap B_n)$ ?

Comment: But isnt it conditional probability?

Comment: We can use the simplest version of the law of total probability. Bear in mind that what you are computing is basically the weighted average probability. See the first formula at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability